# Search for a word inside .txt file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for a batch file to search through a txt file and if it finds the word "Failed" then EXIT 1. Any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is something similar to what Garrett said, but you can run it as a background process while for instance displaying some other info on stdout:

```
@echo off
@start /wait FIND /C /I "SearchPhrase" path-to-your-file\filename.abc
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (do-something)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started...

```
type file.txt | find "Failed"
```

If that returns anything, you set the ERRORLEVEL variable to 1.

Hope that helps dude!

Answer (score 0):

```
FindStr "Failed" YourFile.Txt >Nul:
If ErrorLevel 1  
  ... then it is NOT found (findstr returns 0 if found
```