# Search for a double word inside .txt file using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, duplicates, findstr

I did some research on google for finding the answer on my question 
the only thing i found that was similar too my question was on this site:
[Search for a word inside .txt file using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859775/search-for-a-word-inside-txt-file-using-batch-file)

I made a batch file that is creating a .txt file with 8 lines like this:

> Hello
>
> Mate
>
> How
>
> Are
>
> You
>
> Doing
>
> Bye
>
> Bye

I want to make a batch file that can detect double words inside the text file in this file it must detect `Bye`

In the batch file that also made the .txt file with the 8 lines I want to let it detect the double word `Bye` in the text file and after some research I came to the conclusion that this must be possible with `findstr`.

Can `findtr` detect that the word `Bye` twice occurs?

In my file i want to get a report like this

echo in the text file you made %isn't or there is% a double word
so I want the result of findstr into the variable %isn't or there is%

Sorry if this is a bad question but im new to stackoverflow and im dutch :/
(lot of text translated with google translate)
and can you explain if this is a bad question how i can make it clearer for you

Comment: Must the double words be consective? Or do you still consider it a double if there is another word in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stephan's answer works, but it prints out every replicate word as many times as it appears. It also fairly inefficient, reading the entire file once for every line in the file.

Here is a fairly simple pure batch solution that prints out each replicate word only once. The task is much simpler if you use SORT to group all the replicates together. However, the Windows SORT command ignores case, so the IF must also ignore case. This solution only reads the file twice, regardless of size, once for SORT, and once for FOR /F.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "prev="
set "dup="
for /f "delims=" %%W in ('sort test.txt') do (
  if /i %%W==!prev! (
    if not defined dup echo(%%W
    set dup=1
  ) else set "dup="
  set "prev=%%W"
)
```

If you want the word comparison to be case sensitive, then the above algorithm requires a case sensitive SORT routine. I've written [JSORT.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595) to do just that (among other things). It is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on Windows.

But if you are willing to use a JScrpt/batch hybrid, then the solution becomes very simple if you add my [JREPL.BAT regular expression find/replace utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). The `/M` option allows me to search for repeated words across newlines.

```
jsort test.txt | jrepl "^(.+)$(\r?\n\1$)+" $1 /jmatch /m
```

There is significant initialization time to fire up the JScript engine, so this solution is a bit slower than the pure batch solution if the file is small. But if the file is large, than this is much faster than the pure batch solution.

Comment: Thanks for this post :)

Answer (score 1):

here is something to start with:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (t.txt) do for /f %%a in ('type t.txt^|findstr /x "%%i"^|find /v /c "" ') do if %%a gtr 1 echo %%i
```

`findstr` can't count, so we have to use `find /c` as helper

see `find /?`, `findstr /?` and `for /?` for more information.

Comment: Thanks for helping! this helps me a lot

Comment: can i "convert/change" that %%i to a normal variable like %i%?

Comment: is it possible to output the result of the "for command" to ( output.txt ) ?

Comment: i now have this code 
for /f %%i in (t.txt) do for /f %%a in ('type t.txt^|findstr /x "%%i"^|find /v /c "" ') do if %%a gtr 1 echo %%i >> result.txt it is working but i want to do it in program files and that isnt working like this: 
for /f %%i in (C:\Program Files\something.txt) do for /f %%a in ('type something.txt^|findstr /x "%%i"^|find /v /c "" ') do if %%a gtr 1 echo %%i  i did some research and found program^ files and "programfiles" but it isnt working. is it possible in program files? can you explain?

Comment: i finaly finished it and it works! Thanks for helping